# (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url) with touch phone

Tags: http, java-me, touch, midp, httpconnection

I am working on a J2ME application, it makes a HTTP request and works accordingly to the response received.

Below is my code for HTTP request

```
public String sendHttpGet(String url, String str) throws Exception {
    HttpConnection hcon = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        hcon = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        dis = new DataInputStream(hcon.openInputStream());
        int ch;
        while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
            message.append((char)ch);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){   

    }finally {
        if (hcon != null) {
            hcon.close();
        }

        if (dis != null) {
            dis.close();
        }
        MyForm.show();
    }
    return message.toString();
}
```

It is working fine on non touch devices, but when I checked it on Nokia 500 touch phone,

the code executes till line

```
hcon = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

without throwing any exception, it ends up to show first screen of the application (Main Menu).

Is there any limitation or problem?

Any solution?

Comment: As I can see in your code you're catching the Exception without logging or throwing a runtime exception. Try to log this exception and then print the stacktrace here that we can help yo

Comment: thanks for quick response, i have removed exception message(and logs) from the code above to remove extra code. i checked it by displaying message using Dialog.

Comment: I think your code is correct.Better you check your GPRS/network connection,settings in your mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added permission in jad like this

```
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.http
```

or you can add this permission in netbean by following steps

1. Right Click on project
2. Click on Properties.
3. Click on Application Descripter
4. Select tab API Permission
5. Click on Add Button And from list add `javax.microedition.io.Connecter.http`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, i have added permissions.

Comment: check it, its running or not?

Comment: it is running perfectly fine on non touch phone. but undesired routing to Main Menu on touch phone.

Comment: if this is the issue of the flow, then why is it working on non-touch phones?

Comment: And there is no routing between these two lines of code ---->hcon = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url); dis = new DataInputStream(hcon.openInputStream());<----

Comment: Though i am assign null to all unused objects but can this be an issue of memory leaks?

Comment: how can i get Stacktrace? i know printStackTrace() will be used. where will i get the output on mobile?

Comment: not on mobile, it will print in console, use this staement in catch block e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Application is working fine on emulator. Issue is on touch phone. i have to track it on mobile device. how can i?

Comment: i have cleaned project several times.

Comment: may be You have to be sign in your apllication. Check this link http://browndrf.blogspot.in/2006/06/build-and-install-singed-midlet.html